# Which loss function for ratings

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm have the MovieLens 100k dataset and have join the movie & user datasets together and split the ratings like this:

```python
age                           49
gender                         1
year                        1997
unknown                        0
action                         0
adventure                      0
animation                      0
...
thriller                       0
war                            0
western                        0
occupation_administrator       0
occupation_artist              0
occupation_doctor              0
...
occupation_technician          0
occupation_writer              1
```

In the targets table there are integer ratings going from 1 to 5.

I've currently setup the model like this:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(250, input_shape=(len(X.columns),),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(250, input_shape=(len(X.columns),),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(len(X.columns),),activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but I also tried mapping the ratings with

```python
target = pandas.get_dummies( Y )
```

and then doing:

```python
model.add(Dense(5, input_shape=(len(X.columns),),activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Both yield low accuracies.

What would be the best lost function to use in this case since it's not really categories.  Meaning if the model would predict 1 but the target is actually 5 then the loss should be much higher than if the model would have predicted 4.  That's why I think going at it with categories is a bad idea.
However I want the model to calculate it's accuracy based on the integer value.  Meaning suppose the model calculates 4.2 and the target is 4 then this should be calculated as correct (for accuracy sake, not for the loss).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The one major problem I can see is here:

```
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(len(X.columns),),activation='softmax'))
```

***softmax*** will normalise the output to sum to 1. Since you have only a single output value, it will always be 1, resulting in 20% accuracy if your truth values are equally distributed along the range `[1,5]`.

Try using some other activation functions for the output layer and you should see improvements.

`Mean Squared Error` should work fine as a loss function. Using `accuracy` would be less accurate, surprisingly, so I don't know why you'd want that. But if you insist, you could add a rounding layer at the end:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.round(x)))
```

Comment: Hi MattW, sorry that was wrongly copied.  I did RELU in the first example, the softmax was of the second attempt (with 5 categories).  For the first attempt I'm getting accuracy of acc: 0.0000e+00  which makes me wonder if the accuracy is calculated by comparing the resulting float value or by comparing with the integer value?